# Deploy Rails server on Digital Ocean, works with direct IP address only, not with domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, digital-ocean

Got server deployed in production mode through [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04?comment=23878).

It works on my direct Digital Ocean IP address, but my domain name still shows **ZPanel**

Comment: try to explain your issue with code snippets and what things have you tried to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed mod_passenger?

Have you created the virtual host in your apache httpd.conf?

Have you restarted apache?

Hint: put a index.html file in your application - public/ directory and some gibberish in it, then see if it loads fine in your browser. If it does not, then your apache config needs work, if it does but the Rails app still won't work, you should look at that one instead.